# CSV separator conversion

Tags: csv, separator

I am trying to read many CSV files in US format with separator "," and decimal "."
I want to convert it to French format with separator ";" and decimal ","
see the example below:

**US:**

1,"IT.Neur.EUR.Zt(Bio, 15, 3)",0.832894644842207,0.849419048717047

2,"IT.Neur.EUR.Zt(Bio, 15, 3)",0.767852949784800,0.707998010930148

**French**

1;"IT.Neur.EUR.Zt(Bio; 15; 3)";0,832894644842207;0,849419048717047

2;"IT.Neur.EUR.Zt(Bio; 15; 3)";0,767852949784800;0,707998010930148

i am using C# windows form, i want to reat the CSV and convert it to csv but french format?
Thanks for your help

Comment: What language/platform are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You can do it easily by a small finite state machine with basically 2 states (inside / outside a doublequote delimited field). Outside a string, translate comma and point. Inside, don't.
You'll need a third state because strings can contain (doubled) doublequotes, as far as I remember about CSV.